# Update Option Value in Select box from jquery ajax json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html-select

My current select box looks like this :

```
<select id="select_cat">
<option value="1">Sports</option>
<option value="2">T shirt</option>
<option value="3">Jeans</option>
</select>
```

I am getting one of these options from mysql php and sending it via json where I would like to put the result to the top of the select box.

For example : If mysql returns "T shirt" which has a value "2" I would like my updated select box look like this :

```
<select id="select_cat">
<option value="2">T shirt</option>
<option value="1">Sports</option>
<option value="3">Jeans</option>
</select>
```

What I tried so far :

```
success : function(r){

var obj = JSON.parse(r);

$("#select_cat > :first-child").attr(obj.name, obj.value);

}
```

Console Error : Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ' t shirt' is not a valid attribute name.

That's the best I could do , since I am a noob. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like `obj.name` should be replaced with the string `"value"` because you want to replace the attribute value ... to to replace the text, it would need to also include `.text(obj.name)` before the `;`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with your code is setting the attribute with the name `obj.name` to the value `obj.value`. What you're probably trying to do is setting the `value` to `obj.value`, and the text to `obj.name`:

```
success : function(r){
    var obj = JSON.parse(r);
    $("#select_cat > :first-child").val($.trim(obj.value)).html(obj.name);
}
```

Here, `$.trim` removes all spaces around the actual value.

Comment: I should agree that error is not showing anymore, but the thing is not getting updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
success: function(r){

    var obj = JSON.parse(r);

    $("#select_cat option[value="+obj.value+"]").remove(); //remove the existing element
    $("#select_cat").prepend('<option value="'+ obj.value +'">'+ obj.name +'</option>'); //add the element as first child

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. You don't actually want to change the attribute of the option, like you are trying to do. This is just a demo, but it should be easy to translate to your needs. What I have the `.insertBefore()` function do is move the selected value (in this case hardcoded to 2) to the top.

```js
$(function() {
  var value = 2
  $("#select_cat > [value=" + value + "]").insertBefore("#select_cat > :first-child");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_cat">
  <option value="1">Sports</option>
  <option value="2">T shirt</option>
  <option value="3">Jeans</option>
</select>
```

My guess is that your function will look something like this:

```
success : function(r){
   var obj = JSON.parse(r);
   $("#select_cat > [value=" + obj.value + "]").insertBefore("#select_cat > :first-child");
}
```